# Closing a Database Connection (or similar resource) : Finally{} v/s Finalize()

Tags: servlets, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

I was recently asked this question in an interview.

> Q1 : Where should you close a database connection in a servlet?
>
> A : Ideally, and in most practical applications that I have come across, a database connection is closed in the Finally block.
>
> Q2: Why not in the Finalize method?
>
> A : It would depend on the requirements of the application. Whether it demands us to leave the application open till we reach a point of Garbage Collection so that we can make use of resource/object pooling and get rid of some overhead that might be involved if the connection needs to established back again, or want a secure fail-safe method that would go ahead and close the connection once we are done with the connection.
>
> Q3 What are the pros and cons of closing it in Finally or Finalize? What issues factors will you consider while making that decision?

What would be an ideal answer for Question 3.

Answer (score 1):

Never rely on Finalize as Joshua Bloch indicated in Effective Java

here's a link but consider to read the Effective java book

[the link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=24)

[the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

Answer (score 0):

**Q1 : Where should you close a database connection in a servlet?**

**My View:**  From the layered architecture perspective, You should have seperate layer something like data access layer to deal wit the database connections not directly in your servlet. 
You should always close\release resources (database connection ans so on) in finally block.

**Q2: Why not in the Finalize method?**

**My View:** Generally finally block is guaranteed block where your code will be executed even on failure conditions.but Finalize method has no guarantee that it would be called when you actually calls it directly/indirectly. Garbage collector will call that method before collecting eligible objects.

**Q3 What are the pros and cons of closing it in Finally or Finalize?**

**My View:** Since its not guaranteed that whether finalize() will be called and  its bad practice to keep resource till finalize call.

**Bottom Line:**

> Create/Invoke resources as late as possible and release the resource as early as
>   possible.

Hope this will be helpful..

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, 'servet' was a typo. I indeed meant 'servlet'. Thats sounds like a good exaplanation for this. Thanks!